# Facebook Search API throwing OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the facebook graph search to get informations about urls. So i use the url as search value.

Since a few days, something went wrong, and i don't know why?

ca 30% of the search values throw this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

Here an Example:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=poolhall.de&type=page <- works!

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=pool-hall.de&type=page <- error!

The ony difference: searchvalue

```
"poolhall.de" <-> "pool-hall.de"
```

Another url with error ist search for "horje.de"

```
"horje.de" -> error, "horje" and "horje.com" etc -> no error!
```

But why the "OAuthExeption" is being thrown?
The API does not need an authorisation! Just copy the postet URLs in the Browser adress line, you got an result without auth. Why some search values throws an error and other search values work?

Answer (score 1):

Update: Since roundabout an hour, it looks like Facebook has fixed the bug! no "OAuthExeption" errors anymore!

Answer (score 0):

They're still in beta, I tested this a bit and this really looks like a bug. So probably just need to report about that issue or just wait till this becomes stable.

Comment: just stumbled across s.th. similar, where would you exactly report it?